# Seaborn barplot with error bars only in one direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I'm using seaborn barplot function to plot data from different groups. Is it possible to plot the errorbars only in one direction (only upwards but not downwards)?

This is what I have:

```
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0,100,20), 'group1': ['A','B']*10, 'group2': ['Y','Z']*5 + ['Z','Y']*5 })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=[5,6])
sns.barplot('group1','value','group2',data=df, ax=ax,capsize=.15, lw=1, edgecolor=".2", ci=68) # SEM errorbars
plt.show()
```

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a default option in seaborn, but we can do a trick with `zorder`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=[5,6])

# plot the error bars
# notice the zorder
sns.barplot('group1','value','group2',
            data=df, 
            ax=ax,capsize=.15, zorder=5,
            ci=68) # SEM errorbars

# plot the mean bars
# notice the zorder
sns.barplot('group1','value','group2',
            data=df, 
            ax=ax, lw=1, edgecolor=".2",
            zorder=10,
            ci=None) # no CI errorbars

# handle the duplicate legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[-2:], labels[-2:], title='group2')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it actually seems that one barplot only is enough, like this: `sns.barplot('group1','value','group2',data=df,  ax=ax,capsize=.15, zorder=5, ci=68)`